# ruby open network file fails when run from task scheduler

Tags: ruby, windows

The code:

```
def log_it log_entry
  puts log_entry
  f = File.open("C:/test/test_open_file.log", "a")
  f.puts log_entry
  f.close
end

if File.exist?("C:/test/test_open_file.log")
  File.delete("C:/test/test_open_file.log")
end
begin
  f = File.open("//ServerName/sharename/sample_file.csv", "w")
  puts f.class
rescue Exception => e
  log_it "e.message: #{e.message}\n#{e.backtrace}"
end
```

When I run this from a cmd.exe window it runs fine, but if I run it from a scheduled task, it fails, with the exception

```
e.message: Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - //ServerName/sharename/sample_file.csv
```

I have tried my account (an administrator account) and Administrator itself, but neither work from within the scheduled task. I have selected "Run whether user is logged on or not" and checked "Run with highest privileges", and "Configure For:" is set to Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2".  It is a windows 7 machine. I set "Start in" to the directory where this script resides. Lastly, I tried checking "Run as administrator" on the compatibility tab on the properties dialog for ruby.exe, no difference.

It clearly has something to do with the account that's actually trying to connect to the remote server, but if I'm telling it to use my account, how come I don't have a problem when I run it from the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's having a similar problem, I ended up adding this line:

```
system("net use x: \\\\ServerName\\sharename /user:username password")
```

and changing the File.Open to

```
f = File.open("x:/sample_file.csv", "w")
```

and that did the trick.  Would still like to know how to make the UNC version work, though, if anyone knows...